# spring-security-redirect is not read by spring security 3.1?

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-security

So we're using spring-security-redirect as a parameter in the form that is sent to j_spring_security_check, in order to send the user to the correct page after a successful login. Migrating from Spring security 3.0 to 3.1, this stopped working. We use a subclass of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, overriding onAuthenticationSuccess(), and debugging that method I see that getTargetUrlParameter() returns null. isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl() returns false.

Browsing around I can't find anyone having similar problems... I find some references to AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.DEFAULT_TARGET_PARAMETER, which seems to have disappeared in 3.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I work with Spring 3.1.0 and the redirect works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Spring security 3.1 xsd,

**Attribute : authentication-success-handler-ref**
Reference to an AuthenticationSuccessHandler bean which should be used to handle a successful authentication 
 request. *Should not be used in combination with default-target-url (or always-use-default-target-url) as the 
 implementation should always deal with navigation to the subsequent destination.*

So, in your subclass, you have to perform the redirection.

Comment: Cheers! Now I have a better idea of how to check up these things in the future. I only wish the framework could tell me (via an exception or something) when my implementation is doing something wrong. Maybe that's not always possible.